# How can I authorize gspread when i cannot share my sheet to the service account client_email?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to use gspread to access some sheets at work.

I followed all the steps here -> https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html

However, I am stuck in this step:

> 4. Go to your spreadsheet and share it with a client_email from the step above. Otherwise you’ll get a SpreadsheetNotFound exception when
>      trying to access this spreadsheet with gspread.

Since I'm doing this with my company's Gsuite account, I cannot share my sheet with "external domain".

Below is the message that I get when I try to share my sheet with the service account.

> Sorry, policy set by the administrators of ******* CO., LTD. prohibits
>   the sharing of items with
>   ****@****-269407.iam.gserviceaccount.com, because it is not a
>   Google account in a compatible whitelisted domain.

I am afraid the security guys will be bothered to whitelist this just for me, so i need to find my way around it.

With R, there is no problem accessing my sheet with the 'googlesheets4' package.

I can simply run `sheets_auth()` to get a popup window that lets me log in with my Gsuite account.

Is there any way that I can do this with gspread? Seems like there used to be `gspread.login('xxxx@xxx.com','password')` option before (Which no longer works).

Comment: Indeed, `login()` method, unfortunately, was deprecated by Google API a long time ago. Thanks for the hint on googlesheets4 though, I'll take a look if something similar can be done in gspread.

Comment: @Burnash, FYI googlesheet package in R is deprecated a long time ago. googlesheets4 package still works! I think gargle is the name of the dependant r package that's used for google auth.

Comment: Taeyoung Ahn, thanks for the hint. In gspread version 3.5.0 I've implemented an OAuth2 flow similar to what you've described. Could you upgrade gspread and give it a try? Here's the guide: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-end-users-using-oauth-client-id